# Firebase errors, adding using SPM

Tags: swift, firebase

I have installed Firebase SDK using SPM and i got this, what should i do?
[IMAGE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFbWm.png)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: these are not errors.
just warnings forget about it

Comment: how can i hide it?

Comment: tap on folder button on top of these warnings to show files rather than warnings

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question if they have the same error. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Embed errors and code as TEXT in questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase team is actively working with the gRPC team on this issue and expect to resolve it in the next month or two. It's being tracked at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9790.

In the meantime, the gRPC warnings do not affect Firebase functionality and can safely be ignored.